# a tag with id and css

Tags: css, hyperlink, anchor

I'm trying to output some links with specific hover/active/link attributes:

```css
a#links:link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none
}
a#links:visited {
  color: goldenrod;
  text-decoration: none
}
a#links:hover {
  color: maroon;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps
}
```

```html
<div id="links" class="right" style="margin-right:65px">
  <ul class="nobull" style="margin:0">
    <li><a href="http://com">This link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The link attributes aren't taking though. Syntax error somewhere? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

With `a#links` you give style to all a with id links but you want all a in the div with id "links" so you have to use `#links a`:

```css
#links a:link{
 color:red;
 text-decoration:none}
#links a:visited{
 color:goldenrod;
 text-decoration:none}
#links a:hover{
 color:maroon;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-variant:small-caps}
```

```html
<div id="links" class="right" style="margin-right:65px">
 <ul class="nobull" style="margin:0">
  <li><a href="http://com">This link</a></li>
 </ul></div>
```

Comment: I want to give style only to the  <a> in the parent <div id="links"> not all <a>.

Answer (score 1):

There's no error, well there is but it's in your code.

by stating `a#links` in the CSS file, it will be looking for an `a` tag with the ID `links` appended to it. So you need to add the `id="links"` to the `a` tag, and not to the parent `div` tag like you have.

Or, what I would do, is target your `div` that has the ID, and make the `a` tag the selector in your CSS rules.

```
#links a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none
}
#links a:visited {
  color: goldenrod;
  text-decoration: none
}
#links a:hover {
  color: maroon;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had tried that with #links a:link  { ...} but didn't see a change because of the rest of the page styles. Works now.

Comment: `:link` isn't really needed as you can just target that by using `a`. Is this the outcome you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`a#links` selects an anchor with the ID of links, which doesn't exist. You want `#links a` which selects the anchors that are descendants of the div with the ID of links.

```css
#links a:link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none
}
#links a:visited {
  color: goldenrod;
  text-decoration: none
}
#links a:hover {
  color: maroon;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps
}
```

```html
<div id="links" class="right" style="margin-right:65px">
  <ul class="nobull" style="margin:0">
    <li><a href="http://com">This link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```